# Memory increases steadily using my WebAPI

Tags: c#, c++, memory, memory-leaks, webapi

I am currently building an interface for a given core API. The core is writting in native C and we decided to create a web API as interface, using C# to redirect http requests to the right core function. However, I discovered that memory keeps increasing whenever I make an http request and I don't know why that's the case.

How my System works:

I have an ApiController, mapping http requests to functions, like this:

```
[ApiController]

    public class MethodController : ControllerBase
    {
    public MethodController()
        {

        }
       [HttpGet("load/{name}")]
        public bool load(string name)
        {
            EngineMethods.Marshaller_EngineMethod_Load(name, out bool result);
            return result;
        }
```

EngineMethods is a class used for calling the native c++ function via P/Invoke
The load function gets redirected to this piece of code:

```
        [DllImport(DllFilePath, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        private extern static void load(string name, out bool ret);

        public static void Marshaller_EngineMethod_Load(string name, out bool ret)
        {
            load(name, out ret);
        }
```

the load function is writting in C++. Now I have to make use of the core API that was given me (functions are already implemented). Since the core is not threadsafe I have to use this Mutex for all operations:

```
//it takes a lambda expression as an argument and can return any specified type
template<typename ReturnType, typename FunctionType>
ReturnType EngineMutex(FunctionType lambda)
{
    __try
    {
        enterCriticalSection_engine();
        return lambda();
    }
    __finally
    {
        leaveCriticalSection_engine();
    }
}
```

Making the "load" function look like this:

```
void load(TCHAR *name, bool *ret) 
{
    *ret = false;

    return EngineMutex<void>([&]
    {   
        Core_load(name, ret);
    });
}
```

Now my problem is, that memory keeps increasing when I spam "localhost:xxx/load/something". It seems like old & irrelevant memory won't be released. Garbage Collector from C# wont activate either and if I manually start it, nothing gets cleaned. It seems like I allocate unmanaged memory and don't release it. But all I do is using a function in the core that was given me. And the function that was in the core shouldn't have any memory leaks, because a Software using that core got released a long time ago and spamming that function doesn't make the memory go up. All I can think of are threads that go idle and don't close... I dont know. I looked into the core function and it frees the old name before copying the name it was given as an argument (and it does some other loading stuff I don't understand), but as I said, what the core function does should be irrelevant and not the cause of the problem, but my multiple steps of redirecting the request?

Comment: In the last code block what is `path`? You don't ever use the `name` parameter.

Comment: @walnut I doubt the OP knows the difference between C and C++ with the whole C/C++ thing that's going on now.

Comment: Modified the function parameters to make it more simple. The load function gets two TCHAR arguments (name and path) but I removed one to make it more simple.